# Counting words occurances in a string using Dictionaries

Tags: loops, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of each word in a string. i then want to return the results as a dictionary, having the words as Keys and their number of occurrences as Values.
However, when i run my code it returns the statement: `line 8, in word_counter builtins.TypeError: string indices must be integers` i dont quite understand what it means by this.

```
def word_counter(input_str):
    lower_sentence = input_str.lower()
    dictionary = {}
    words = set(lower_sentence.split())
    for word in words:
        if word in input_str:
            input_str[word] += 1
        else:
            input_str[word] = 1
    return dictionary
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First i think you meant :

```
dictionary[word]+=1
```

instead of `input_str[word] += 1` but its not the way for this task.It also will raise a `KeyError` exception.

You can simply use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) as a more pythoinc way for such tasks.

```
from collections import Counter
print Counter('this is a sent this is not a word'.split())
Counter({'a': 2, 'this': 2, 'is': 2, 'word': 1, 'not': 1, 'sent': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks!. but instead i've used the `.count()` function as `lower_sentence.count(word)`. and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Moh'dH Welcome, yep you can use `count` method but `Counter` is more efficient for long strings!